# Why does this syntactically invalid C# code compile?

Tags: c#, syntax-error

I discovered this quite by accident, but I had apparently written some incorrect code in a much larger project. I've reduced it to an MVCE, and am curious why it even compiles. I accidentally added what the system appears to be treating as a variable name after a type check in C#, and it appears to be treating as an alias to the variable I was type checking. You can test in the dotnetfiddle below.

Does anyone have an explanation for what on earth is going on here?

For reference I'm using vs2017 enterprise with a .net 4.6.1 project.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string foo = "hello world";
        if (!(foo is string str)) { return; }
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

[image: h̸̰̏̐́͗e̸̖̥̞͆̓̋́ ̷̺̘͉̍̒̂̄ċ̴̟̻̣͚͑̂o̶̲͐̊̈́̉m̷̜̩̀̂͛e̴̳̅̏̌͝ṣ̵͇̏]

https://dotnetfiddle.net/BwT1kx

Comment: It's valid in C#7: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#type-pattern

Comment: @UnholySheep "varname is assigned within the if statement only" why can he access `str` outside the scope of the if statement?

Comment: @MikeTheLiar well technically the declaration is NOT in the if block :)

Comment: @MikeTheLiar "The scope of varname is from the is expression to the end of _the block enclosing the if statement_", note that's not the if block itself, but the one that encloses the if statement, i.e. the outer `Main` body block in this example.

Comment: I imagine the blue squiggles are because you are testing if a variable of type `string` `is` of type `string`, which will always be `true` (unless `foo` were `null`, which it also knows is not the case).  What does it say if you hover the mouse over either of the red squiggles?

Answer (score 4):

Not a bug, but a feature! that's the pattern matching supported by the `is` keyword [since C# 7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#pattern-matching-with-is)

For some reason, your IDE is using the wrong C# version for analysing the code and giving you incorrect squiggly lines.

Comment: I would say visual studio showing it as invalid is a bug, but good to know. :)

Comment: @Sidney: The compiler can tell based on static analysis that `foo` can never be `null` and therefore will always be a `string` instance at that point. It's only a warning to indicate that your expectations of what `foo` could be are incorrect.

Comment: @madreflection I haven't inspected the syntax highlighting rules by default but it's definitely telling me it has no idea of what "str" is on line 11.

Comment: It's strange that it's using different versions for analysing and compiling (as you're saying it compiles fine). That seems like a broken installation.

Comment: I've experienced mismatches/desyncs like that before.  Unloading the project (or sometimes the solution) and reloading tends get the analyzer and the compiler back in sync.

Comment: @Sidney is it possible that you use Resharper and it is actually Resharper that is being confused not Visual Studio. I think I recall those red text styles being a way of Resharper showing where something is unrecognized.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature called [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#pattern-matching-with-is) as others pointed starting from C#. If you are interested in what compiler translates this to you can check [compiler generated code](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFAEg1uVAzAAlnuAdmQG9kVYZyykc766o4AGHAMwHsOcBeHAIgAWAUwA2o7gHcOAJ1HB+AbnIoAlmxwAKAISbO3VQGcCrQwBcZASks4SeQooC+KpgE5N5q8tQUH5Z0iOQA===).

Notice how in Release mode compiler makes static analysis that `foo` is always a string type and omits most of the generated code in Debug.